# Kali Linux stucked at finish the installation step

Tags: virtualbox, grub, kali-linux

I am currently installing Kali Linux on my 32 bits Windows 10 pro laptop on virtual box. It took me almost 10 hours to get to the stage of setting up grub. During the grub setup, the Kali Linux stucked and also the progress bar.

[image showing the kali linux installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uNCP.jpg)

Please how can I solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you get the Kali 32-bit installer?  Easy to grab the 64-bit version.

Comment: Yes, I got the 32 bit installer